# nested :has_many cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am working with the `cocoon` gem to create a nested form, 3 objects deep. I have the first set of objects working just fine, rendering the new partial and adding to the records, but in trying to add in another nested `has_many` related object, the form is rendering, but the object is not saving properly. [Full code "views and models" here.](https://gist.github.com/4173335bf56275489664)

Answer (score 1):

needed to add `objects_attributes` in to my `dashact.rb attr_accessible` statement

(which is not in the docs at all)